# Show only row with highest value

Tags: sql

In my query I'm returning number of days a week something occurs. Everything is working fine, with the exception that I'm getting multiple rows returned where I only need the highest. So for example in my query, if the TotalDays is 3, I have a row for 1, 2 and 3. If its 4 then I have rows for 1,2,3 and 4, etc. What do I need to do so that I only get the highest one? I tried using both ROW_NUMBER and MAX but can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this with the CASES.

```
SELECT Employees.CustomerID, X.*, Customers.ReportID
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DaysofWeek
    FROM
        Customers
    ) X, Employees INNER JOIN ON Employees.EmployeesID = Customers.EmployeesID
GROUP BY Employees.CustomerID, Customers.ReportID, X.DaysofWeek
```

Few more details on this. For any given EmployeeID there can be unlimited ReportIDs and I want to return all of them but ONLY for where the DaysofWeek is the highest.

So EmployeeID 200 may have report 1001 and 1002 that are returned 2 days a week each. What should shows is

```
200     2     1001
200     2     1002
```

However, what is currently showing is:

```
200     1     1001
200     2     1001
200     1     1002
200     2     1002
```

Modified the query and added a couple more tables though everything is returning a value of 5.

```
WITH sub AS(
SELECT Shift1.EmployeeID, X.*, Schedule.Services, Schedule.ReportID
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DaysofWeek
    FROM
        Schedule
    ) X, Shift1 INNER JOIN (Shift2 INNER JOIN Schedule ON Shift2.Shift2ID = Schedule.Shift2ID) ON Shift1.Shift1ID = Shift2.Shift1ID
GROUP BY Shift1.EmployeeID, Schedule.Services, Schedule.ReportID, X.DaysofWeek
)
SELECT X.*
  FROM sub X
  JOIN (SELECT EmployeeID, ReportID, MAX(DaysofWeek) AS DaysofWeek
          FROM sub
         GROUP BY EmployeeID, ReportID) Y
   ON X.DaysofWeek = Y.DaysofWeek
   and X.EmployeeID = Y.EmployeeID
   and X.ReportID = Y.ReportID
```

Comment: why is there a CustomerID field on the Employee? I can't figure out your schema. You refer to 200 as EmployeeID in your comments, but you have Employees.CustomerID in your SQL statement.

Comment: I think you are getting some sort of auto-join with the customers table. You are selecting things from the Customers table, which technically isn't one of the tables you are selecting from. Be clearer to include ReportID and employeeID in X

Comment: I had a lot more data in my query so I stripped away several joins and additional data that didn't apply to this specific question. However, in this case we have an employee that would be the sale rep for a given customer which is why there is a customer ID field within employee.

Comment: but you already have EmployeesID no the customer. So you are saying there is a one to one relationship between employees and customers?

Comment: Actually there are about 5 more tables that I'm joining but I omitted all but the first and last in this case to shorten up the code.

Comment: but the result is completely invalid. It gets an error, so all your answers have invalid sql as well. You show ReportID on Customer table, which means 1 report per customer. CustomerID on Employee, so one customer per employee. You can't get the results you claim.

Comment: here is a fiddle of your question, with some corrections. If you can get it to behave as you claim, then you might get an answer that works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7786d/1

Answer (score 0):

The query itself might be able to get cleaned a little better, however if your current query is working and showing you the output you've indicated, but you want to reduce it to what you indicate is your desired output, you should be able to use the with clause to do this as follows:

```
with sub as(
SELECT Employees.CustomerID, X.*, Customers.ReportID
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DaysofWeek
    FROM
        Customers
    ) X INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.EmployeesID = Customers.EmployeesID
GROUP BY Employees.CustomerID, Customers.ReportID, X.DaysofWeek
)
select x.*
  from sub x
  join (select customerid, reportid, max(daysofweek) as daysofweek
          from sub
         group by customerid, reportid) y
    on x.daysofweek = y.daysofweek
   and x.customerid = y.customerid
   and x.reportid = y.reportid
```

Also your join clause was off.

Comment: The problem with this is that it shows all values as 5, even if the highest for one for a given CustomerID and ReportID is 1.

Comment: @doby48 think I just left out a join for the reportid, can you try re-running it as edited? Also in this case you should more easily be able to just use max on the inner query, however in the event that you also want to select additional columns that wouldn't work whereas the above should work.

Comment: No such luck still shows only 5's for all values. If I remove the MAX(DaysofWeek) then I do see all the duplicates again so my guess is the issue is somewhere in there.

Comment: @doby48 if that does not work then the query and result you posted cannot be correct, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48936a/1/0 , if you are really getting the output you've provided with the query you've provided, the above query will reduce it to what you've said you wanted.

Comment: I added another table to my query and am still getting all 5's for the DaysOfWeek when using MAX. Posted my updated code above. Any suggestions on what I'm still doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, your query should look like:

```
SELECT e.CustomerID, c.DaysOfWeek, c.ReportId
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             (CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             ) AS DaysofWeek
      FROM Customers c
     ) c JOIN
     Employees e
     ON e.EmployeesID = c.EmployeesID
GROUP BY e.CustomerID, c.ReportID, c.DaysofWeek;
```

I question the join (why would `Employee.CustomerId` not join to the `Customers` table?), but this is how you have it.  To get the reports with the biggest day of the week, use `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT e.CustomerID, c.DaysOfWeek, c.ReportId
FROM (SELECT c.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.EmployeesId ORDER BY DaysOfWeek DESC) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT c.*,
                   (CASE WHEN [M] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN [Tu] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN [W] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN [Th] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN [F] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN [Sa] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN [Su] = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    ) AS DaysofWeek
            FROM Customers c
           ) c
     ) c JOIN
     Employees e
     ON e.EmployeesID = c.EmployeesID
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY e.CustomerID, c.ReportID, c.DaysofWeek;
```